# How to stop PowerPoint from flipping photo

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, pictures, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

Using PowerPoint 2011, there is a predefined theme called "Revolution".  The "Picture with Caption" slide contains a picture placeholder on the left side of the slide.  The problem with this theme is that the picture placeholder is automatically flipping my photos horizontally.  This is really pointless and annoying since my photos contain text.  Then on some of the photos, it's totally changing the aspect ratio and squishing them in various directions.

I can individually edit each photo but that seems to screw up the embedded borders, rounded corners, and other properties specific to the theme.

I thought it would be best to edit the master "Picture with Caption" slide, however, I cannot see the option(s) that tells it not to flip the picture or change the aspect ratio.

I simply want to drop in a photo and drag it around within the picture placeholder without any automatic distortion or mirroring.  Other themes have picture placeholders that work properly, and I'm simply looking for an explanation about how to edit the placeholder within "Revolution" to make it behave like those.

Comment: Can you delete the supplied picture placeholder and put in one of your own? (Or copy one from a theme which has a picture placeholder which works properly.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, "deleting and replacing" the placeholder would involve trying to re-integrate it into the theme with the proper borders, cropping, placement, etc.  I should just be able to "edit" it.